# Spark Scala - I need nth row of the group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I exploded a column and got the dataframe as below:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------------+
|serialnumber|   roomname|             devices|
+------------+-----------+--------------------+
|hello       |Living Room|             device1|
|hello       |Living Room|             device2|
|hello       |Living Room|             device3|
|hello       |Living Room|             device4|
|hello       |Living Room|             device5|
|hello       |    Kitchen|             device1|
|hello       |    Kitchen|             device2|
|hello       |    Kitchen|             device3|
|hello       |    Kitchen|             device4|
|hello       |    Kitchen|             device5|
|hello       |   Bedroom1|             device1|
|hello       |   Bedroom1|             device2|
|hello       |   Bedroom1|             device3|
|hello       |   Bedroom1|             device4|
|hello       |   Bedroom1|             device5|
|hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device1|
|hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device2|
|hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device3|
|hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device4|
|hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device5|
|hello       |   Bedroom3|             device1|
|hello       |   Bedroom3|             device2|
|hello       |   Bedroom3|             device3|
|hello       |   Bedroom3|             device4|
|hello       |   Bedroom3|             device5|
+------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Now I want a dataframe as below, that means 1st of Living room, 2nd of Kitchen, 3rd of Bedroom1 and so on....

```
   +------------+-----------+--------------------+
    |serialnumber|   roomname|             devices|
    +------------+-----------+--------------------+
    |hello       |Living Room|             device1|
    |hello       |    Kitchen|             device2|
    |hello       |   Bedroom1|             device3|
    |hello       |  Bedroom 2|             device4|
    |hello       |  Bedroom 3|             device5|
    +------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: How do you maintain the order of roomname? Like how does "Living Room" has "device1"?

Comment: @koiralo, To maintain this order I have a column with nested array (room_name:['bedroom1', 'bedroom2'], devices: ['device1', 'device2']), 

So in order to get the column 'roomname' I explode the column using (explode(col("nestedColumn.room_name")).
Similary for device (explode(col("nestedColumn.devices"))

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with `groupBy` and `window` function but you need to know an Order of the `column`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy("serialnumber").orderBy("roomname")

df.groupBy("serialnumber", "roomname")
  .agg(collect_list("devices").as("devices"))
  .withColumn("index", rank().over(window))
  .withColumn("devices", element_at($"devices", $"index"))
  .drop("index")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
|serialnumber|roomname   |devices|
+------------+-----------+-------+
|hello       |Bedroom 2  |device1|
|hello       |Bedroom1   |device2|
|hello       |Bedroom3   |device3|
|hello       |Kitchen    |device4|
|hello       |Living Room|device5|
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: I am using spark version 2.2.0. So, I am not able to use 'element_at'
Are there any alternates to 'element_at'?

Comment: In that case you can write an UDF and pass devices and index and get the element back from UDF

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the problem you are having is you lose the order of roomname when you are using explode.

Assuming that roomname is of type Array[..], instead of using `explode` you can use `posexplode`

```scala
 val df = Seq(
    ("hello", List[String]("room1", "room2")),
    ("hello1", List[String]("room1", "room2"))
  ).toDF("serial", "roomname")


df.select(posexplode($"roomname")).show()
```

will give you the following output

```
+---+-----+
|pos|  col|
+---+-----+
|  0|room1|
|  1|room2|
|  0|room1|
|  1|room2|
+---+-----+
```

you can then select the "n-th" row as required by adding a `filter`